# Call Objective C method from Swift

Tags: objective-c, xcode, facebook, swift

I keep getting this error:

```
<unknown>:0: error: swift frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
Command /Applications/Xcode6-Beta2.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift failed with exit code 254
```

What I am trying to do:
Sign in with facebook. I have the objective C code for logging in (from their sample projects) but I am using Swift as I do not know Objective C.

How can I call the objective C method from swift?

here is my objective C code:

```
// If the session state is any of the two "open" states when the button is clicked
    if (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateOpen
        || FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateOpenTokenExtended) {

        // Close the session and remove the access token from the cache
        // The session state handler (in the app delegate) will be called automatically
        [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];

        // If the session state is not any of the two "open" states when the button is clicked
    } else {
        // Open a session showing the user the login UI
        // You must ALWAYS ask for public_profile permissions when opening a session
        [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile"]
                                           allowLoginUI:YES
                                      completionHandler:
         ^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {

             // Retrieve the app delegate
             AppDelegate* appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
             // Call the app delegate's sessionStateChanged:state:error method to handle session state changes
             [appDelegate sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
         }];
    }
```

And my swift code:

```
var bridgeForFacebook: Bridge = Bridge()

@IBAction func fbSubmit(sender: AnyObject) {
    bridgeForFacebook.signIn();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be that the code files don't quite *see* one another correctly, and thus can't play nicely.

When you use Objective-C code from within a Swift file you need to bridge the header from your Objective-C class into Swift. Normally this is done automatically when you create a new Objective-C file.

You need to create an Objective-C heading file called `(your project name)-Bridging-Header.h`. In that file, write a `#import` statement and import the heading file for any Objective-C classes you want access to in Swift.

Now head over to your project build settings and find the "Objective-C Bridging Header" field under the "Swift Compiler - Code Generation" section. In there, fill out the relative path to your new bridging file (should be `(project name)/(project name)-Bridging-Header.h`).

Then your classes and method calls should work as expected.

Source: [Swift with Cocoa, Swift and Objective-C in the Same Project](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-XID_75)